# GRUB installation fatal error in Ubuntu 11.10 installation

Tags: grub2, system-installation

I have Windows XP and Windows 7 on my HD and have just installed the Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop on the HD too. I decided to install boot files on a `/boot` partition and also install GRUB not at the MBR and install EasyBCD as a bootloader manager in Win7. Here are my hard disk partitions:

```
/dev/sda1 winxp(ntfs)
/dev/sda5 win7(ntfs)
/dev/sda6 my other ntfs partition
/dev/sda7 /boot
/dev/sda8 swap
/dev/sda9 /
```

I selected `/dev/sda7` as device for boot loader installation. I followed steps from [this article on setting up dual boot](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/22/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-11-04/).

But I get a fatal error on installing GRUB at the final step of Ubuntu installation:

```
Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda7   
Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda7' failed
This is fatal error
```

How can I solve it? Should I reinstall Ubuntu or just reinstall GRUB? Is it a bug in Ubuntu 11.10? Can I reinstall GRUB from a knoppix live cd? I don't have an Ubuntu live CD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error message when I *accidentally* specified a partition (like you did, `/dev/sda7`) instead of the drive (`/dev/sda`).  The bottom line is that you may have to install GRUB in the MBR of `/dev/sda` and let GRUB manage the booting of Linux and Windows.  The article you referenced mentions this at the bottom.

To do this:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

I don't think you'll have to update grub, but it can't hurt, since it will simply rebuild `grub.cfg` and ensure that the Windows OSes are in the GRUB menu.

```
sudo update-grub
```